# XSLT how to sort inside a <apply-templates>

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello im studying XML from w3schools and now im studying this example above.
I learned that we can use  inside a for-each and understood this.
But now im trying to use  inside  but its not working.
I already tested in many ways but nothing works, can anyone give a little help?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
      <xsl:apply-templates/>  
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
      <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title">
          <xsl:sort select="title" order="descending" /> <!--The sort script-->
        </xsl:apply-templates>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
      </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
      Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
      <br />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="artist">
      Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
      <br />
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Greatest Hits</title>
            <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>RCA</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1982</year>
        </cd>


    </catalog>
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing what the input document looks like.

Comment: I forgot, sorry! I update now!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to sort **cds** by artist - not **titles** by artist. You cannot sort titles (directly) by artist anyway, because artist is not a child of title. And it wouldn't matter anyway, unless you had more than one title in a cd.

Answer (score 0):

you've got to sort "cd"s based on "title", and this is the way I think you were looking for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
      <body>
          <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
          <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/cd">  
                <xsl:sort select="title" order="descending"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```